# Nginx Ingress Selective Reverse Proxy Location Rewrite

Tags: nginx, proxy, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress

I have an Nginx Ingress that I'm trying to use to replace my HTTPD reverse proxy.

One of my servers behind the proxy returns a redirect containing this url https://proxy/endpoint. Originally with my HTTPD reverse proxy, I was able to modify outgoing http/https traffic headers (specifically location) and regex the proxy to the proper external dns name. How can I achieve this with Nginx Ingress. I see

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to
```

Essentially I would like to modify the outgoing traffic to change the location from https://proxy to whatever I need it to be.

Answer (score -1):

It was indeed those two fields I had to add as annotations to my Ingress.yaml. Once those were in place, things got routed correctly.

Comment: but how do you use them? I can't get my head around it.

Comment: @TomasJansson, where are you using this? Is this within Rancher?

Comment: I was using it in kubernetes on gke on google cloud. I couldn't figure it out, so switched to traefik, and that was somewhat easier to get working.